# Image is not showing up or covering the whole available area of the View in react-native-element card component

Tags: react-native, react-native-image, react-native-elements

I want to set up a card from react-native-elements, which has an Image and the title of the card. I want the image to take the whole of the width available in the view and adjust the height keeping the aspect ratio. So basically I have neither height nor width.

As I understand, the Image component requires height/width props. But setting it up won't make it responsive. I was trying few things with flex but it's not working

```
<Card>
 <Image
    style={{
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    width: null,
    height: null
  }}
    resizeMode="contain"
    source={{
    uri: "url-of-the-image.png"
  }}/>
  <View>
    <Text>Image Title</Text>
  </View>
</Card>
```

Image is not showing up

Comment: <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <Card>
                <Image
                    style={{
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30
                    }}
                   
                    source={{uri:'https://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/frontdoor/creative/PanoramicImagesRM/FD_image.jpg'}} />
                <View>
                    <Text>Image Title</Text>
                </View>
            </Card>
          </View >
use this

Comment: Do you know the width of the Card?

Comment: by default it use full width and you can give width in style also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some of the things, it appears that i had missed the props of the react-native-element Card Component.

There is an image prop in the react-native-element which does all that what is required.

To someone who may find it useful, this is what i did finally

```
<Card image={{uri: "url-of-the-image.png"}}>
  <View>
    <Text style={styles.tag}>{tags}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
either use
ImageBackground tag with resizeMode="cover" instead of View tag
or
Use resizeMode="cover" inside image tag.

This should solve your problem.